# function returning object with max value

Tags: vb.net, linq, entity-framework

I’m using EF and LINQ (VB-NET) and I want to find  the object (row) with maximum  ID value.
I want to do something like this:

```
var item = db.Items.OrderByDescending(i => i.Value).FirstOrDefault();
```

But I need a function GetMaxObj that returns the object whit max ID value.

```
Function GetMaxObj (function)
End function
```

Where function is ex. Function(f) f.ID. 
I want the selection part taking plase on the server, I do not want to return the whole result set, only the max ID object.

I want to use my function like this:

```
item = unitOfWork.MyRepository.GetMaxObj(Function(f) f.ID)
```

I can not figure out how I can write my function… can somebody help me with this please?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim query = db.Items.Max(Function(x) x.value )
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But this will return only the maximum value not the whole object? I need the whole object...

Comment: Try with List<T>.Max() it returns a Items object

Comment: Thanks again! But what will my parameter to my function look like? How can I pass my parameter: "function(f) f.ID" to my function, I hav to do something like this Function GetMaxObj(ByVal maxFilter As IQueryable) or...??